# I'm trying to perform a text search on fields in mondo db using pymongo but getting TypeError: skip must be an instance of int

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have created indices already, my queries run fine without including the projections in `find()` function, the moment I add `{"_id" : 0}`in find i get the following error

```
TypeError: skip must be an instance of int
```

I couldn't understand why I am getting this error, what is the meaning of this error ?

Here is the query I am running using pymongo :

```
cursor = db.web_docs.find({ "$text" : { "$search": "stack" } },{ "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } }, [{"_id" : 0, "prev" : 0, "content" : 1, "url" : 1,"score" : 1}] ).sort( [('score' , {'$meta': 'textScore'} )] ).limit(4)
```

Comment: can you show the query that be caused the error ?

Comment: This query creates problem, I ran it using pymongo db.web_docs.find({ "$text" : { "$search": "stack" } },{ "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } }, [{"_id" : 0, "prev" : 0, "content" : 1, "url" : 1,"score" : 1}] ).sort( [('score' , {'$meta': 'textScore'} )] ).limit(4)

Answer (score -1):

TypeError: skip must be an instance of int

This means you have a variable named skip and you try to use it as an int.

Something like:

someint = otherint + skip

Search for that variable.